# requireJS 2.1.5 dependencies out of order for nested require

Tags: dependencies, requirejs

So here is a flow of my code:

```
main.js --> jquerymobile --> router --> extra --> lib1 --> lib2
```

In extra.js, after load up lib2, I set up my module

```
//extra.js
require( ['lib1'], function () {
        $("#body").append('<p>got lib1</p>');
        require(['lib2'], 
            $("#body").append( '<p>got lib2</p>' );
            window.stuff = true;
            $("#body").append( '<p>set my module</
        });

});
```

And in my router.js, I use my module after load up extra:

```
//router.js
require(['../extra'], function() {
        $("#body").append( '<p>using my module</p>' );
        console.log( window.stuff );
    });
```

I am expecting my module to be set up before it is used in router.js. However, this is the order I get:

```
set my router
using my module
got lib1
got lib2
set my module
```

And of course I get undefined when I try to use my module (window.stuff).

Here is a demo for this error: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19311981/demo.zip

Can you guys help me to figure out what I did wrong in specifying my dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way you can ensure that lib1 and lib2 are loaded when extra returns is to use the [define syntax](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#defdep) and declare them as dependencies up front. Doing it later is analogous to any other async call. You can't know when it's going to return.

```
//extra.js
define(['lib1', 'lib2'], function(lib1, lib2) {
    $("#body").append('<p>got lib1</p>');
    $("#body").append( '<p>got lib2</p>' );
    window.stuff = true;
    $("#body").append( '<p>set my module</
    return something;
});
```

You might also want to reconsider using global window.something variables as a communication method from the module. Instead, have the module return some object that you can use:

```
//router.js
require(['../extra'], function(extra) {
    $("#body").append( '<p>using my module</p>' );
    console.log( extra );
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the reason to use nested require in `extra.js` is that is to guarantee `lib1.js` is loaded before `lib2.js`. Putting them in require array for define will load both of them, but I think it won't specify which one should be load first.

Comment: if lib2 requires lib1 then it should be define'ed that way, similar to what I proposed above with extra.js

Comment: Thank you very much. `lib1` and `lib2` are not my code, they are downloaded. So, at first I would like to let them remain untouch. (If someone maintains my code, he may overwrite the define pattern when downloading new version). But it seems like using `define` syntax upfront is the only way to manage this. I now have them in correct order. Again, thanks for your propose answer. I will mark it the correct answer now.